# Use a function declared in `mod.rs` in the same directory

Tags: rust

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
tests /
|_mod.rs
|_common.rs
```

Inside `mod.rs` I have a number of functions like e.g. `hash` that I am trying to use inside `common.rs`.

I tried doing this by having `use self::mod::hash` but it does not seem to work. How can I include and use the functions inside `mod.rs` in other files of the same directory?

Note: I have changed the structure currently, having all the functions I need to use inside an `utils` module and using that instead. I am just curious as to why it was not working.

Comment: Putting a `mod common;` inside `mod.rs` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name “mod” is purely a name for the file, and not at all a module name (just like `lib.rs` does not define a module named `lib`), so a path containing `::mod::` is never meaningful. Rather, the file `src/tests/mod.rs` provides the contents of a module named `tests` (or `crate::tests`).

So, assuming that `src/tests/mod.rs` contains `mod common;` as is normal, the way `src/tests/common.rs` refers to a function `hash` defined inside `src/tests/mod.rs` is as `super::hash` or `crate::tests::hash`.